# Change ADF Query Panel's Default Component

Tags: oracle-adf

In my JSPX page, I created a search page by drag-n-dropping the View Criteria (VC) to the page. By default the component's are text box. What I want to do is change some of them to use other components, such as the selectOneChoice component, with binding from another Entity Object (EO), or maybe add a date picker to it.

Is this possible? Or do I have to stick with the defaults?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is all stuff that can be done in your view object under Attributes. For date attributes, make sure that the type is set to date. I've'nt done this one but for the selectOneChoice component, I'm assuming you can define a list of values on the desired attribute that is based on another view object. Also look in the Control Type field of the Control Hints when you edit an attribute.  If you are using bind variable with your search I believe you can define these properties there also.

Comment: I was following a tutorial earlier on which asked to add fields from another Entity Object (EO) which I want to create as List of Values (LOV). By doing that, I couldn't get the drop down to show. But with your suggestion, which is to define an LOV on another View Object, now that works. Thanks. :)